# How to make Terraform use the AWS credential_process?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'd like to use the `credential_process` configuration option in `~/.aws/config` to source credentials for the AWS provider in Terraform.

I see that support for `credential_process` was [recently (9 days ago) added to the AWS GO SDK v1.16.4](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/commit/275272fc5c7fdea1719f5851925dc5d9df27f89d). I also see that the AWS GO SDK dependency was [changed to that version in the Terraform AWS provider even more recently (11 hours ago)](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/commit/0de48e05c3817022a8d28ab484467b3ef8c14ce1).

Once the next Terraform AWS provider version (apparently v1.52.0) is released do I automatically get support for the `credential_process` functionality?

With Terraform v0.11.10 and provider.aws v1.51.0 the `credential_process` does not appear to be used, as I get the following error:

`* provider.aws: error validating provider credentials: error calling sts:GetCallerIdentity: NoCredentialProviders: no valid providers in chain. Deprecated.`

I do have `AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG=1` in the environment as [suggested by the SDK documentation](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/sdk-for-go/api/aws/credentials/processcreds/). Is that needed with Terraform or does it load `~/.aws/config` anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `credential_process` configuration option works with Terraform v1.52.0 and later. So to answer the my own question, I just needed to wait for the release.

As noted by others, the `AWS_PROFILE` environment variable can be used to select a profile. This is not specific to using the `credential_process`, though.

Answer (score 3):

Use `AWS_PROFILE` *and* `AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG`:

```
AWS_PROFILE=foo AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG=1 terraform plan
```

Issue discussing profile vars and credential_process: https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/issues/6913

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is export AWS_PROFILE="x" and terraform will use it.